# mysql name based on batchnumber generate

Tags: mysql

I have created a table customer
     but when I insert the first name ex: anish the batchnumber its can generate automatically when i give first name 'anish'  its would be taken first 3 character it should be select 'ani' after '001' is added
    if have a more than 1 same name given its batch number should get increment

Here I  added a sample Output

```
Firstname | Batchnumber
---------------------

Anish     |  Ani001
Uma       |  Uma001
Anish     |  Ani002
Uma       |  Uma002
Loki      |  Lok001
```

Comment: Please add your table definition. Please clarify if the batchnumber should be generated when you insert the entry or if this is a query. Please specify if you can insert more than one entry at the same time. Please specify what should happen if you change a firstname (e.g. what is the result if you rename the first Anish to Uma; and then: what is the number a third Anish should get after the first one got renamed to Uma).

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @ndx = 0;
SET @cur_hash = '';
SELECT id,Firstname ,CONCAT(left(Firstname ,3),IF(ndx>=0,CONCAT('00',ndx),'')) Firstname 
FROM (SELECT id,
   @new_hash := MD5(Firstname ),
   (@ndx := IF(@new_hash=@cur_hash,@ndx+1,1)) ndx,
   @cur_hash := MD5(Firstname ),
   Firstname 
FROM (SELECT id,Firstname FROM customer ORDER BY Firstname ) AA) A order by id;
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   |  Anish     |  Ani001
2   |  Uma       |  Uma001
3   |  Anish     |  Ani002
4   |  Uma       |  Uma002
5   |  Loki      |  Lok001
```